# Can not upload document via zoho api

Tags: php, api, php-curl, zoho

Using curl request from Laravel.

```
    $path =  storage_path('app/letters/letter.pdf');
    $post = '@' . $path;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sign.zoho.com/api/v1/requests');
    $authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $zohoAccessToken;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [$authorization]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
    $entriesData = ['data' => [
        'requests' => [
            'request_name' => "NDA ",
            'actions' => [
                'recipient_name' => 'test',
                'recipient_email' => $mail,
                'action_type' => 'sign',
                'verify_recipient' => false,
            ],
            'is_sequential' => false,
        ]
    ]];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($entriesData));
    $output = curl_exec($ch)
```

And getting the error response: "message": "Extra key found", "status": "failure", "code": 9015,

I'm using this code to get access token and it works well

```
        $data = [
            'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
            'client_id' => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $secret,
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'
        ];
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Why do you set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`   twice.

Comment: @IndraKumarS I need to pass 2 parameters : path to file and description.
Ok i merged that two parameter into  $entriesData array but got same error

Comment: “Extra key found” sounds like you are sending _more_ data, then this endpoint expects. Where is the documentation for the particular action you are trying to undertake here located?

Comment: @CBroe
https://www.zoho.com/sign/api/#document-management

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [API documentation](https://www.zoho.com/sign/api/#create-document) and this [post](https://thisinterestsme.com/php-upload-file-curl/), I believe that this should look something like:

```
$path =  storage_path('app/letters/letter.pdf');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sign.zoho.com/api/v1/requests');
$authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $zohoAccessToken;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [$authorization]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
  'data' => json_encode([
    'requests' => [
      'request_name' => "NDA ",
      'actions' => [
        'recipient_name' => 'test',
        'recipient_email' => $mail,
        'action_type' => 'sign',
        'verify_recipient' => false,
      ],  
      'is_sequential' => false,
    ]   
  ]), 
  'file' => curl_file_create($path)
];
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

With that, it seems to produce approximately the same payload as a CURL command line invocation as per the API documentation.

The main source of confusion for me was having `data` being the key for the field, and the corresponding value being JSON encoded.